# CBCentralManager State originally registers as .unknown

Tags: swift, cocoapods, core-bluetooth, completionhandler

I have built my own cocoapod. There is a public function called `activateBluetooth()` to allow the developer to easily start their bluetooth connections. Here is what the pod looks like so far:

```
import Foundation
import CoreBluetooth

public class Service: NSObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate {

    public static let shared = Service()
    private lazy var centralManager: CBCentralManager = {
         return CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    }()

    private override init() {
         super.init()
    }

    public func activateBlutooth(completion: () -> Void) {
        centralManagerDidUpdateState(centralManager)
        completion()
     }

    public func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        switch central.state {
        case .unknown:
            NSLog("unknown")
        case .resetting:
            NSLog("resetting")
        case .unsupported:
            NSLog("unsupporting")
        case .unauthorized:
            NSLog("unauthorized")
        case .poweredOn:
            NSLog("poweredOn")
        case .poweredOff:
            NSLog("poweredOff")
        }
    }
}
```

In my application I want to call `activateBluetooth()` and then do something in the completion handler. Here is what the ViewController looks like:

```
import UIKit
import Toolkit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        Service.shared.delegate = self
        Service.shared.activateBlutooth {
            //Do something here, currently the state is unknown
            //Need the state to be powered on
        }
    }
}
```

The issue I face is that originally I am getting the central manager state as unknown and only after 3 seconds or so does the state become powered on and I am able to do something. How can I, on the `Service` side of things make sure that the state is already powered on by the time the completion handler runs?

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll need to decide what to do if the BLE never becomes available. It may be powered-off. It could be forbidden by MDM profile. Do you want to just wait in those cases (possibly forever), or do you want to call the callback with an error?

In either case you'll need to hold onto the completion handler until it's ready to be used.

You could store it like this:

```
var powerOnCompletion: ((Bool) -> Void)?

public func activateBlutooth(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    // Fancy way to chain together multiple calls to `activateBluetooth`. You could also just be
    // simple and `powerOnCompletion = completion`
    let previousHandler = powerOnCompletion
    powerOnCompletion = { result in
        previousHandler?(result)
        completion(result)
    }

    if centralManager.state == .poweredOn {
        powerOnCompletion?(true)
        powerOnCompletion = nil
    }
}
```

Then you can also call it in `centralManagerDidUpdateState`:

```
public func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
    switch central.state {
    case .unknown:
        NSLog("unknown")
    case .resetting:
        NSLog("resetting")
    case .unsupported:
        NSLog("unsupporting")
    case .unauthorized:
        NSLog("unauthorized")
        powerOnCompletion?(false)   // error, and it's going to improve soon
        powerOnCompletion = nil
    case .poweredOn:
        NSLog("poweredOn")
        powerOnCompletion?(true)
        powerOnCompletion = nil
    case .poweredOff:
        NSLog("poweredOff")
        powerOnCompletion?(false)   // error, and it's going to improve soon
        powerOnCompletion = nil
    }
}
```

Depending on your system, you may also want to think about other transitions like going from on to off, and adjust this as needed. But the basic approach is that you're going to have to hold onto the completion handler.

That said, I generally go ahead and create the `CBCentralManager` during `init` (rather than using `lazy`). That way, it's generally ready by the time anything comes looking for it.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. It took me a little bit to parse it all out but I think I got it now. I was trying something similar, but not quite as complete as your answer. I gave it a shot and it works! Thanks again for the help!